# Using \lstinputlisting to include a file but only certain lines or line ranges

Tags: listings

I wanted to tidy up a TeX document and was curious if you can use `\lstinputlisting` or a similar function to include a certain part of a source-code file.

Example, I have a 500 or so line source file and I want to include just lines 300-400.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Each "listing" environment understands the `firstline` and `lastline` keys:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=300,lastline=500]{file.cc}
```

Comment: Thanks =) I also just found this in the reference (4.4 - The printed range). But I asked because I had trouble finding it :)

Comment: Personally I think `linerange` is more succinct

Comment: Only as an expansion of egreg answer, I would add that using the `matlab-prettifier` package works also pretty well. It is intended for Matlab (and compatible) language only, but the command `\lstinputlisting[label={code:label},caption={Caption},firstline=100, lastline=300]{Matlab_Code/file.m}` works greatly

Comment: As a remark, I would suggest that also the option `firstnumber=100` is really nice; it allows you to keep track of the code you cutted.

Answer (score 53):

listings supports line ranges not only with `firstline` and `lastline` (see egregs answer) but even with `linerange={<first1>-<last1>,<first2>-<last2> …}`. Note, that `first2` has to be greater than `last1` and so on. So

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-4,7-9}]{file.cc}
```

would be valid but

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange={7-9,1-4}]{file.cc}% Don't do this!!!
```

is not allowed!

For more information see section 4.3.3 "The printed range" at the [listings manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: ...but note that the line numbering using this option will be continuous - so if you want to make it obvious that you haven't printed some code , using @egreg's approach multiple times (possibly with some explanatory text along the lines of "setup routine omitted" or even just `$\vdots$` and specifying `firstnumber=` might be better.  A `firstnumber=firstline` option would be nice.

Comment: @ChrisH: You can also use my suggestion more than once with only one range every time and add something like `$\vdots$` between.

Comment: @ChrisH: Unfortunately, the `float` argument cannot be used in that case, as the two listings need to stay together. Also, I fear there are conflicts with the frames, as `listings` puts frames around single listings, rather than the whole set of listings that should be considered as one listing (with omissions).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, if you say so, I believe you - and I can see why it would be true.  I've never floated my listings so haven't experienced this (my listings have all been in appendices and run to several pages each even with the most boring bits skipped).

Comment: Can we also insert a line `...` between two line ranges to indicate the existence of the lines that are not shown?

Comment: @yildizabdullah AFAIK the package does not support this. So in such a case you have to use multiple `lstlisting` environments and put the `\dots` or `\vdots` between them yourself.

Answer (score 20):

As an addendum to egreg's answer: If you are typesetting line numbers and want these numbers to reflect the physical line numbers, the `firstnumber` key comes at your rescue:

```
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,firstnumber=300,firstline=300,lastline=500]{file.cc}
```

Comment: Yup thanks, I have found that already in the reference, but didn't read section 4.4. Do you know how I can skip line 149 of my file as it contains a string too long for the bounding box. Error "Dimension too large " ... ""

Comment: @Supernovah: Use either `linerange`, or split your `\lstinputlisting` into two separate instances that skip line `149`.

Comment: The compiler still hiccups with linerange splitting over 149

-Excuse me it actually doesn't, thanks - I had a syntax error and the IDE was using an old file