# Choosing lines from a Matlab file using matlab-prettifier

Tags: listings, matlab

I have been using the `matlab-prettifier` package a couple of times. So far I have only imported the entire .m-file to be shown in my documents using:

```
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
```

in the preamble and:

```
\lstinputlisting{../mFile.m}
```

in the documents.

In my upcoming `beamer` presentation I want to show only some part of my code, e.g. lines 10-15. Is this somehow (easily) possible?

I usually use the documentclass `memoir` for my writings. Is the solution the same/easier here? (If it exists.)

Comment: Harish answered your question, but this one may also be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200125/read-integers-from-external-data-file-to-document-programming-code-in-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matlab-prettifier` is built on top of `listings`. Hence you can use `linerange={<first1>-<last1>,<first2>-<last2>, and so on}` (which is a `listings` option) to print selected lines. For example:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab with line range},linerange={3-6}]{sample.m}
```

Now lines 3-6 of `sample.m` will be printed.

Code (from one of Jubobs old answer):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{person.m}
classdef person
   properties %(here, properties is a keyword)
       mass=80;
       height=1.80;
   end
   methods
       function BMI = getBMI(height,weight)
           BMI = person.mass/person.mass²;
       end
   end
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
%% Code sections are highlighted.
% System command are supported...
!gzip sample.m
%   ... as is line continuation.
A = [1, 2, 3,  ... % (mimicking the ouput is good)
     4, 5, 6]
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
x=1; %% this is just a comment, though
% Context-sensitive keywords get highlighted correctly...
p = properties(mydate); %(here, properties is a function)
x = linspace(0,1,101);
y = x(end:-1:1)
%   ... even in nonsensical code.
]end()()(((end end)end ))))end (function end
%{
    block comments are supported
%} even
runaway block comments
are
\end{filecontents*}

\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[caption = {Some class definition}]{person.m}

Before you use any "for"~loop, refresh your memory on Matlab blocks.%
\footnote{Any occurence of "for" must have a matching "end".}

\lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab with line range},linerange={3-6}]{sample.m}
%% \lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab with line range},linerange={3-6,10-15}]{sample.m}
\lstinputlisting[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]{sample.m}
\pagebreak

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while "\ph{condition}"
  if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is same for `memoir` too.

Comment: The `...` somehow got replaced by `\dots`. Is that something your editor does automatically?

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, winedt does such things whether we like or not. But only if we install some macros, hence no default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within the `listings` package, using the following syntax.

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=10, lastline=15]{../mFile.m}
```

This will work in `beamer` and `memoir`, as well as other classes.

See also: [Using \lstinputlisting to include a file but only certain lines or line ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/using-lstinputlisting-to-include-a-file-but-only-certain-lines-or-line-ranges)
[Wikibooks LaTeX: Source Code Listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Using_the_listings_package)