# Automated Code Listing Line Numbers

Tags: macros, listings, minted, external-files, parsing

I want to automate source code examples in my documentation.  Listing comes very close to doing this as it allows specification of start and ending line numbers:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=300,lastline=500]{file.cc}
```

See: [Using \lstinputlisting to include a file but only certain lines or line ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/using-lstinputlisting-to-include-a-file-but-only-certain-lines-or-line-ranges)

However, source code tends to be a living document.  I would love some way to markup my code with some kind of `EXAMPLE_BEGIN` and `EXAMPLE_END` type of tag in the comments and let that define the bounds for the listing.

If this isn't possible with a current package, I'm not opposed to writing one that does this.  If that's the case, is there a good starting point?  (i.e. Modifying Listing? Modifying Minted? Parsing with a macro?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):.

> Instead of using `linerange` with line numbers, one can use text
>   markers. Each such marker consists of a , , and a
>   . You once (or more) define prefixes and suffixes and then use
>   the marker text instead of the line numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents*}{livingdocument.txt}
  Here some text which will not be included
  EXAMPLE_BEGIN
  1. All these texts will be included
  2. All these texts will be included
  3. All these texts will be included
  EXAMPLE_END
  Here some text as well which will not be included
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[linerange=EXAMPLE\_BEGIN-EXAMPLE\_END,includerangemarker=true]{livingdocument.txt}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

*(Those shifts must be coming from the default language settings.)*

---

For more details please see Section 6.8
Multicolumn Listings in [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).